# How to run this BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I want to parse the bitcoin private keys from github on bigquery
and i cant run this code

```sql
SELECT
 f.repo_name,
 f.path,
 c.pkey
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files` f
JOIN (
 SELECT
    id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r'(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0=9])(5[HJK][123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]{48,49})(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])') AS pkey
 FROM
    `bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents`
 WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(content, r'(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0=9])(5[HJK][123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]{48,49})(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])') c
ON
  f.id = c.id
)
```

```
Query Failed

Error: Encountered " <ID> "c "" at line 15, column 140. Was expecting: <EOF>
Job ID: anton-e4584:US.bquijob_743dcb53_16a8e5ca058
```

Comment: I`ve disabled legacy SQL https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: And i`ve got this error Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "c" at [14:147]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parentheses.  I would also phrase this as standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT f.repo_name, f.path, c.pkey
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files` f JOIN
     (SELECT id,
             REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r'(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0=9])(5[HJK][123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]{48,49})(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])') AS pkey
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents`
      WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r'(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0=9])(5[HJK][123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]{48,49})(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])')
     ) c
     ON f.id = c.id;
```